# How to make a docker swarm network in a public network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-swarm

I want to create a swarm of docker nodes over machines in different networks. Say, a instance in AWS and another in GCP.

I have succesfully created a swarm between 2 GCP instances using their individual public IP addresses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a swarm of containers on AWS and GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58017142/make-a-swarm-of-containers-on-aws-and-gcp)

Comment: I am sorry. Made a duplicate. Deleted the previous one

Comment: You should have deleted this one. You had your answer on the previous one.

Comment: Actually the previous question was not accurate so I made a new one. Sorry for the inconvinience. Also, it didn't solve my problem for swarm across public networks.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts

The following ports must be available. On some systems, these ports are open by default.

- TCP port 2377 for cluster management communications
- TCP and UDP port 7946 for communication among nodes
- UDP port 4789 for overlay network traffic

If you plan on creating an overlay network with encryption (--opt encrypted), you also need to ensure ip protocol 50 (ESP) traffic is allowed.

**Notes**

- Exposing these ports to the internet poses significant security risks
- Performance of an overlay network between two separate data centers will suffer.

Comment: Sir, I am able to make a swarm on a private network but not over a public network. How do I do it in public network?

Comment: You have to make sure that the ports above are open and that the swarm nodes have static, public IP addresses. This gist appears to have more info: https://gist.github.com/jesugmz/2bbf41f947c6f5fb33fbb3aa2b84b2b8